# Adding collaborator to project during reservation

Tags: ibm-q-experience

If I add a collaborator to an IBM Quantum Education project during a system reservation, do they immediately get priority access to the reserved system?  Or do I need to add them before the reservation starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add at any time. The reservation system cares about the project you send the jobs from, not the individual users.